# Port Scanning with WebSockets

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

Recently [a post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=23246170) was featured in Hacker News about websites abusing WebSockets to find open ports on the client's machine.

The post does not go into any details, so I decided give it a try.

I opened a web server on port 8080 and tried running this script in Chrome's console:

```js
function test(port) {
  try {
    var start = performance.now();
    var socket = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:' + port);

    socket.onerror = function (event) {
      console.log('error', performance.now() - start, event);
    }

    socket.addEventListener('close', function(event) {
      console.log('close', performance.now() - start, event);
    })

    socket.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
      console.log('open', performance.now() - start, event);
      socket.send('Hello Server!');
    });

    socket.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log('message ', performance.now() - start, event);
    });
  } catch(ex) {
      console.log(ex) 
  }
}
```

Indeed Chrome logs different a error message (`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`) when I try to connect to a port that is not open:

```
test(8081)
VM1886:3 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8081/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And when I try to connect to a port that is open but is not listening to WebSockets (`Unexpected response code: 200`):

```
test(8080)
WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

But I can't find any way to access and read these errors in JavaScript.

Control flow does not reach the catch clause `catch(ex) { console.log(ex) }` and the event objects that Chrome passes to `socket.onerror` do not seem to be any different whether the port is open or not.

Timing attacks also don't seem to be helping at least in Chrome. Delta time between `onerror` and `new Socket()` creation seems to increase after calling `test(...)` a few times.

So is there actually a way for a web page to determine if a port is open on my computer?

Answer (score 0):

The presentation slides linked to below show it was well known in 2016 and lack of a timing difference in your tests show mitigations may have been applied upstream.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/meeting/96/materials/slides-96-saag-1/

Answer (score 0):

It might only work on windows:
https://blog.avast.com/why-is-ebay-port-scanning-my-computer-avast